# Making ColorSetter work like a PasteButton

Tags: dynamic, color

I might be missing something obvious here. I am building a palette for constructing code to make certain graphics. The idea is that my colleagues can click buttons instead of having to know the right commands. So `PasteButton[]` is an obvious help. Where I have gotten stuck is in color definition. What I want is for the user to be able to select a color on a `ColorSlider`, and then click a button to paste the `RGBColor[]` value selected in that `ColorSlider` at the notebook insertion point. I do *not* want the code pasted in this way to update subsequently when the user chooses a different color in the `ColorSlider`

This is what I have so far, but the resulting pasted code does not pick up when the user has selected a different color in the slider. Pasting `Dynamic[col]` instead of `Setting[col]` results in a piece of code that changes when a different color is selected in the slider, which as I mentioned is not the desired behaviour.

```
Grid[{{PasteButton[
    Graphics[{Dynamic[col], Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> 26], 
    Setting@col, ImageSize -> 26, ImageMargins -> 0, FrameMargins -> 0], 
   ColorSlider[Dynamic[col], ImageSize -> {75, 25}, 
   AppearanceElements -> "Spectrum"]}}, Spacings -> 0, Alignment -> Bottom]
```

[image]

The idea is that the user clicks on a color in the spectrum zone, and then clicks the button on the left that looks like a swatch.

How do I modify / rewrite this code to achieve the desired behaviour?

Comment: Wrap `Dynamic` around your entire widget.

Comment: Yep @LeonidShifrin is right - it's working ;) Maybe this will come handy too `Button["color", FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["ColorSelectorDialog"]]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wrap your entire widget (as currently shown in your code), in `Dynamic`, it will work. The reason is that without it, changes is `col` are not propagated to `PasteButton`.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution.

I have made 2 modifications on your code:

`ButtonPaste[]` replaced by `Button[]` (the Attributes are not the same)
`Setting[]` (useless) replaced by `Paste[]`

Full code :

```
   Grid[{{
    Button[
       Graphics[{Dynamic[col], Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> 26], 
           Paste[col], 
           ImageSize -> 26, 
           ImageMargins -> 0, 
           FrameMargins -> 0], 
       ColorSlider[
           Dynamic[col],
           ImageSize -> {75, 25}, 
           AppearanceElements -> "Spectrum"
           ]
       }}, 
    Spacings -> 0, 
    Alignment -> Bottom
    ]
```

`Button[]` has the attribute `HoldRest` (`ButtonPaste[]` has not), so the `col` (of `Paste[col]`) is only evaluated when the Button is clicked.